# Overriding sub-dependencies with Yarn

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

Looking for a way to control sub-dependencies while using Yarn. I have a package but I do NOT want to include the css dependency. In npm, this was easy as below:

```
{
  "name": "my-application",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "latest"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "lodash": {
      "main": "./dist/lodash.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how this can be accomplished using Yarn?